# How can I access a resource or file from one Homebrew formula in another's `install`?

Tags: homebrew

I have one formula "A" that installs stuff in its `share` directory, and I want to know how to read the directory from another formula("B")'s `install`.  Is it possible?

Do I need to install A's resources into `etc.` instead of `share`?  Or how can I share data between packages?

I would use B's data as a `resource`, but it's got its own build process, so then I thought having its own formula would be better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might get better answers on https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer here: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1636

tl;dr: Use `Formula["a"].share`. The index is a lower camel case string.